# How to remove the full stop at the end of each bibliography entry?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Using biblatex how do I remove the last full stops in the following entries:

> [1] Peter Fox, Richard Rabbit, and Franc Bird. “Animals are the better hu-
>        mans”. In: Horse and Hound 10 (2011), pp. 11–15.
>
> [2] D r Mathematician. How to do all the typographic editing for free. Open
>      Access, University, 2012.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{liu:11,
  author = {Peter Fox and Richard Rabbit and Franc Bird},
  title = {Animals are the better humans},
  journal = {Horse and Hound},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {10},
  pages = {11--15}
}
@BOOK{bibbook,
    title = {How to do all the typographic editing for free. },
    publisher = {Open Access, University},
    author = {Mathematician, D r},
    year = {2012}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152892/how-to-delete-a-full-stop-on-reference-ending) changes the bib file which is undesired, as this bib file is used to generate other bibliography styles as well.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: It is required for the bibliography style of a few journals, such as the Journal of Engineering Mathematics.

Comment: Strange that they'd have such an awkward requirement without giving you a style file that implements is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this has been answered elsewhere, but I can't find it. Add the following redefinition to your preamble (somewhere after `\usepackage{biblatex}`)

`\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}`

This redefines the `\finentrypunct` macro which, according to the `biblatex` manual, controls *"the punctuation printed at the very end of every bibliography entry, usually a period. The default definition is a period."*

Answer (score 5):

You can modify/remove the very last punctuation with:

```
\renewcommand*\finentrypunct{}
```

Comment: Thank you, that also works perfectly! What difference does the `*` make?

Comment: \newcommand* or \renewcomand* make sure no paragraph/linebreak occurs in their content. In your case you can use the starred version or not, it doesn't make any difference.