# dot at end of reference in text

Tags: biblatex

I am using the command `\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{}` to suppress the
dot at the very end of biblatex references, which seems to work.  I am
now trying to come up with a `\fullcitebib` command to print references within
the main text, formatted the same as in the references.  I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{crys2010,
  author =   {David Crystal},
  title =    {An Encyclopedic Dictionary of Language and Languages},
  publisher =    {Blackwell},
  year =     {2010},
  edition =      {3},
  address =      {Oxford},
}
@InCollection{herm2006,
  author =   {Rachel Hermetet},
  title =    {\emph{The Criterion} et les litt\'{e}ratures
                  europ\'{e}ennes, 1922--1935},
  booktitle =    {Revues Modernistes anglo-am\'ericaines: lieux
                  d'\'{e}changes, lieux d'exil},
  publisher =    {Ent'revues},
  year =     {2006},
  editor =   {Beno\^{i}t Tadi\'{e}},
  pages =    {189-200},
  address =      {Paris},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {\list{}
   {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
     \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}\item}
  {\usedriver
     {}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry
   }
  {\item}
  {\endlist
   }
\begin{document}
\fullcitebib{crys2010,herm2006}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which produces this

[image]

How can I get rid of the dot at the end of references created with my new command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{}
```

go with

```
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
```

The problem arose because normally we have `\newbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry}` and amongst other useful things, the macro `\finentry` prints the `\finentrypunct`. If you redefine the bibmacro `finentry` to do nothing, you don't get to see the `\finentrypunct` (but you are also missing a reset of some internal helpers). But in your `\fullcitebib` you call `\finentry` directly, and that still prints `\finentrypunct`.

The proper solution to get rid of the punctuation at the end is thus to make `\finentrypunct` empty with `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}`. See also [How to remove the full stop at the end of each bibliography entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187443/35864)