# Prevent bibliography from having a fullstop after each item

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to be able to remove the auto-generated full stop at the end of each of my bibliography items.

This is what I get when running the code included below:

[image: Bibliography output]

I would like to **not** have those full stops at the end of each line.

I have tried using `\gobbledot` as specified in the accepted answer for [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419580/bibliography-prevent-periods-from-being-added-after-citation-notes) but I get the error:

```
! Use of \gobbledot doesn't match its definition.
\blx@theformat #1->#1\isdot
```

Working example below.

Main file:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[block=par,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{bibliography}

\begin{document}
Hi, I am an example ~\cite{jez}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bib file:

```
@misc{ jez,
    title = {What is Continous Delivery - Continous Delivery},
    howpublished = {\url{www.continuousdelivery.com}},
    note = {Retrieved 01/05/2019}
}
```

These files have been massively abbreviated for clarity. But they result in the image shown above, which shows the same issue.

EDIT:
After implementing @moewe 's answer. My bibliograpy looks like this:
[image: Bibliography after answer implemented]

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187443/35864

Comment: @moewe That removes the fullstop for the date (note), but not for the link or the title. I would like to remove the fullstop for all three if possible

Comment: The `\gobbledot` trick is only a sly workaround for BIbTeX-generated bibliographies, it is quite unlikely to work with `biblatex`. Note that  `biblatex` knows the `url` and `urldate` fields, so you could say: `url = {http://www.continuousdelivery.com}, urldate = {2019-05-01},` instead of the using `howpublished`/`note` workaround for old BibTeX styles. `example ~\cite{jez}` has one space too much, you probably want `example~\cite{jez}` or `example \cite{jez}`, but not both.

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}`?

Comment: @moewe Using the `url` and `urldate` fields and also `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}` removes the dot from the name and leaves one after the date (which I don't care about).
Thank you :) I will set this as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get rid of the last period (the one at the end), see [How to remove the full stop at the end of each bibliography entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187443/35864).

Getting rid of all periods at line breaks is a bit tricker. As a first approximation

```
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}
```

should do the right thing most of the time.

---

As mentioned in the comments, since you are using `biblatex` you may want to consider using the dedicated fields `url` and `urldate` instead of the `howpublished`/`note` workaround for older BibTeX styles. You can also use the type `@online` instead of `@misc`

```
@online{jez,
  title   = {What is Continous Delivery -- Continous Delivery},
  url     = {http://www.continuousdelivery.com},
  urldate = {2019-05-01},
}
```

---

Instead of

```
 example ~\cite{jez}
```

you probably want

```
 example~\cite{jez}
```

or `example \cite{jez}`, but not both a space and `~`.