# Remove period at end of bibliography items

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, punctuation

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\nocite{test1,test2}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

And the bibliography file contains the following:

```
@misc{test1,
    title = "\href{http://www.blah1.com/}{Title 1}"
}

@misc{test2,
    title = "\href{http://www.blah2.com/}{Title 2}"
}
```

The output PDF file contains "Title 1." and "Title 2." with their corresponding hyperlinks. The bibliography looks ugly because of the periods at the end of the entries. I wonder if there is a way to discard the period and have "Title 1" and "Title 2" instead.

Comment: These are not complete bibliography entries so this is not really a bibliography proper. Even if the source is essentially a web site and there is no author, no organisation responsible and no date, you'd at least provide a date accessed in a proper entry. (And it would be weird if no other details were required and available!)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer given by @daleif in [How to delete a full stop on reference ending](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152892/how-to-delete-a-full-stop-on-reference-ending), I added the line

```
\newcommand\EatDot[1]{}
```

to the preamble in the main file, and amended the bibliography file to:

```
@article{test1,
    note = "\href{http://www.blah1.com/}{Title 1}\EatDot",
}

@article{test2,
    note = "\href{http://www.blah2.com/}{Title 2}\EatDot",
}
```

The output file is:

```
[1] Title 1
[2] Title 2
```

There is no period at the end of the entries.