# natbib: spurious period in bibliography items with DOIs

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I encounter this problem with both the [MSCS style file](ftp://ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/mscs-cls/unpacked/mscs.cls), which is not a standard LaTeX package but an in-house style of Cambridge Journals, and also with the ACM [sigplanconf](http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/sigplanconf.cls) style. I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask about in-house styles here, but if so I would appreciate some help. I don't believe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152892/how-to-delete-a-full-stop-on-reference-ending) is related.

I get a spurious period at the end of bibliography items whenever they contain DOIs, as shown below (the very last period should not be present): 
[image]

Here's the code for the above; you'll need to put `mscs.cls` in the same folder.

```
\documentclass{mscs}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{milner92,
 author = {Robin Milner and Joachim Parrow and David Walker},
 title = {A Calculus of Mobile Processes, {I} and {II}},
 journal = {Inf. Comput.},
 volume = {100},
 number = {1},
 pages = {1--77},
 year = {1992},
 doi = {10.1016/0890-5401(92)90009-5},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\citep{milner92}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bib.bib}

\end{document}
```

Note: `natbib` doesn't seem to be essential to the problem, but I would like a solution that works with it.

Comment: If you want to use the style of [Mathematical Structures in Computer Science](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=msc), why don't you get the official version, at ftp://ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/mscs-cls/unpacked/mscs.cls ?

Answer (score 2):

For some (weird) reason, this spurious period is due to the `doi` field be filled.
If you remove it, the bibliography prints properly:

```
\documentclass{mscs} % Downloaded from ftp://ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/mscs-cls/unpacked/mscs.cls
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{milner92,
author={Robin Milner and Joachim Parrow and David Walker},
title={A Calculus of Mobile Processes, {I} and {II}},
journal={Inf. Comput.},
volume={100},
number={1},
pages={1--77},
year={1992},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{milner92}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Yes, this is silly and their style should implement doi's, which are really convenient.
If you're planning to submit to that journal, I guess they will re-format your bibliography anyhow, so my advice would be not to spend too much time to adapt their bibliographic style.

Comment: I changed my mind about accepting this answer (although it's helpful), as the problem also arises with sigplanconf. So the problem seem to be particular to DOIs, rather than the MSCS style per se. Unfortunately removing DOIs isn't a good option for me, so I really need a fix that works generically with natbib. Also updated my question.

Comment: @Roly I would upvote your question a socend time, if that was possible `;-)`. You should provide an example file which reproduces your problem with Sigplanconf.

Comment: Agreed. I will do that next week once my deadline has passed!