# Eliminate period at the of title in a BibTex reference and add a comma after it (also make it emph and eliminate quotes)

Tags: bibtex, formatting, bibliographystyle, wiki

I need to cite a Wikimedia image, so following the instructions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia#BibTeX_entry, I created a bib item like this:

```
@misc{pict2,
   author = "{Wikipedia contributors}",
   title = "Plagiarism --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
   year = "last accessed 2004/12/02",
   url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Plagiarism&oldid=5139350",
   note = "[Online; accessed 22-July-2004]",
   howpublished = "\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Plagiarism&oldid=5139350}"
}
```

I use `\bibliographystyle{JHEP}` (it can be found here: https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP_TeXclass.jsp).
Now, the output is like the one in the screenshot.

[image]

I want to eliminate the period at the end of the title and add a comma after it.
I tried the \EatDot approach ([How to delete a full stop on reference ending](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152892/how-to-delete-a-full-stop-on-reference-ending)), but it complains that

```
--line 28 of file biblio_MDN_CB.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 39 of file biblio_MDN_CB.bib
 :    title = "Plagiarism --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia"
 :                                                                 \EatDot,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
```

Also: how can I make the title italics/emph AND without quotes?
This is how it works for article and that's how I would it to be for Wikimedia pages too:

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify (a copy of) `JHEP.bst`, calling it `JHEP-mod.bst`.

Change lines

```
    383 FUNCTION {format.title.p}
    384 { title empty$
    385     { "" }
    386     { "``" title "t" change.case$ * ".''" * }
    387   if$
```

to

```
    383 FUNCTION {format.title.p}
    384 { title empty$
    385     { "" }
    386     { "``" title "t" change.case$ * "''" * } % <--- here
    387   if$
```

and lines

```
     75 FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
     76 {
     77   's :=
     78   output.state mid.sentence =
     79     { " " * write$ }
     80     { output.state after.quote =
     81             { ", " * write$ }
```

to

```
     75 FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
     76 {
     77   's :=
     78   output.state mid.sentence =
     79     { ", " * write$ } % <--- here
     80     { output.state after.quote =
     81             { ", " * write$ }
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, I'll try it! How could I also make the title appear in \emph and without quotes?
I just managed to narrow down the cause to the `howpublished = "\url{address}"` line.

Comment: @kingworld In this case I suggest to change all occurrences of `format.title.p` into `format.title` (except where the former function is defined).

Comment: Thanks! It seems it's working exactly as I wished! Many cheers :)